# Show that vector field has no polar angle function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

Let $A = \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{ (0, 0) \}$ and let $f : A \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a vector field such that $f(x,y) = (-y,x)$.

Show that there exists no polar-angle-function of $f$ on $A$.

*(Hint: integrate $f$ over the unit circle)*

---

I am struggling to solve this exercise. I do not understand what integrating over the unit circle tells me about the existence of a polar-angle-function. The integral over the unit circle is $2\pi$. Does anyone have a hint?

**EDIT 1:**

A *polar-angle-function* (name translated from German) is a function $\theta : U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that a curve $\alpha : U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{ (0,0) \}$ can be represented as

$$ \alpha(t) \enspace = \enspace |\alpha(t)| \cdot \Big( \cos \theta(t) \, , \; \sin \theta(t) \Big)^T$$

**EDIT 2:**

I calculated the integral of $f$ over the unit circle as follows: Let the unit circle be parametrised by $\gamma : [0,2\pi) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 : t \longrightarrow \big( \cos t, \sin t \big)^T$. Then the integral is:

\begin{align}
\oint_{S^1} f(x,y) \, d\gamma \enspace &= \enspace \int_0^{2\pi} f \big( \gamma_x(t), \gamma_y(t) \big) \cdot \dot{\gamma}(t) \, dt \\
&= \enspace \int_{0}^{2\pi} \Big( - \sin t, \cos t \Big) \cdot \Big( - \sin t, \cos t \Big) \, dt \\
&= \enspace \int_0^{2\pi} \underbrace{\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t}_{= \, 1} \, dt \\
&= \enspace 2 \pi
\end{align}

**EDIT 3:**

*Lemma:* Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be star-shaped with respect to $x_0 \in \Omega$. Let $g: \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}$ be a continuous vector field. Then there exists a continuous map $\vartheta: \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that

$$g(x) \enspace = \enspace |g(x)| \cdot \Big( \cos \vartheta(x), \sin \vartheta(x) \Big)$$

for all $x \in \Omega$. The function $\vartheta$ is called the polar-angle-function and is unique up to addition of a konstant function $x \longmapsto 2\pi j$ for some $j \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is the definition of a "polar angle function on $f$"? As far as I can tell, this usage is not standard

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to a [potential function](https://mathinsight.org/gradient_theorem_line_integrals) corresponding to $f$.

Comment: I translated it from German, I didn't know what the correct English word was. However, I updated my question so that the notion is explained now.

Comment: There's no well-defined continuous polar angle function $\theta$ on any open set containing the origin. The vector field $f$ turns (tangent to the unit circle) once around the origin.

Comment: Are you sure about your claim about the integral over the circle? To me, $\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}f = \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{it})ie^{it}\mathrm{d}t$, and noticing that $f(e^{i}) = ie^{it}$, we get $0$.

Comment: I wrote down my way of calculating the integral, see EDIT 2.

Comment: You did not use the right definition of line integral. There should no be a dot product but a product of complex numbers: $\int_0^{2\pi} i e^{it} \times ie^{it} \mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{2\pi} -e^{2it}\mathrm{d}t = \left[ -\frac{e^{2it}}{2i}\right]_{t=0}^{2\pi} =0$.

Comment: Moreover, the function you defined is the restriction of the holomophic map $z \mapsto i\times z$ on $\mathbb{C}^*$. As an holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, its integral along any closed curve vanishes. Maybe you did not write the right function in your question?

Comment: Hm, I used the definition that wikipedia also uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field . My underlying space here is $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\mathbb{C}$. I am aware of the similarities between them - however, in order to keep things simple, I'd rather stay on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The results should be the same, shouldn't they?

Comment: Right, we are not talking about the same object. I was misunderstanding your question and thought about line integral of the scalar field $f$. Sorry about that.

Comment: Given Edit 3, the point to consider is whether there exists a continuous $\theta:A \to \mathbf{R}$ such that $f(x, y)/|f(x, y)| = (\cos \theta(x, y), \sin\theta(x, y))$. As a separate but related matter, does it make sense why there is no continuous choice of polar angle function on the punctured plane as in Ted's comment? <> Your proposed function $\arcsin(x_{1}/r)$ doesn't work, because any particular branch of $\arcsin$ takes values in an interval of length at most $\pi$, and we need $\theta$ to map onto $[0, 2\pi]$ (or some interval of length $2\pi$).